# What's the term used when the first word of one page is repeated at the end of the previous page?

Tags: typography, terminology, history

There's a common feature in old typography where the first word of a page is repeated at the end of the previous page, usually right-aligned on a line by itself.  [This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=wDQVAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) from 1759 shows this feature on nearly every page.

For example, page eleven could end with:

> A sentence like this starts near the end of page eleven and
>
> then

On page twelve you find:

> then continues at the top of page twelve.

What do you call this feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some digging, I found it is called a [catchword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchword).  Read more about it here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65963/in-old-books-why-is-the-first-word-of-the-next-page-printed-at-the-bottom-of-th

I always assumed this was to improve readability, as the reader could continue more seamlessly onto the following page, but it turns out it was also printed there to aid the bookbinder in ensuring that the pages were in the correct order.

Comment: And just to make things confusing, 'catchwords' is also a term that applies to these in typography: https://www.google.com/search?q=catchwords&tbm=isch

Comment: Interestingly, this feature has its roots in ancient papyrus scrolls and manuscripts into the Middle Ages. It's also called a reclamans (plural: reclamantes), from Latin: reclamare 'call out'. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reclamans