# How to add catchwords using InDesign

Tags: typography, adobe-indesign, history

Many books before 1800 used a feature called *catchwords*, repeating the first word of the page at the bottom of the previous page.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchword) has a small article on them and there's a good question about them on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65963/in-old-books-why-is-the-first-word-of-the-next-page-printed-at-the-bottom-of-th).

*How can I add these to my document using InDesign?*

I'm using InDesign CS6.  Somehow I imagine there isn't a way to do this (short of some horrible script to run) but I'm not sure.

Comment: I highly doubt there will be any automated method for catchwords. You'll have to manually set them. It's an antiquated practice that serves little purpose anymore.

Comment: If there is a way, then it will be through scripting. Google points to the free Catchword Generator for InDesign CS5, written in AppleScript by Jakko Westerbeke: http://software.understairs.nl/mac/catchwordgenerator.html Someone well versed in scripting for InDesign using JavaScript might port that script for InDesign in Windows.

Comment: Hey, there's no reason to down-vote because you don't like the idea. It's still an interesting question.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: if it is javascript and runs from within InDesign, it *should* work on Windows as-is. (?)

Comment: NM missed the applescript bit

Comment: This is closely related to yesterday's http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/first-word-of-one-page-is-repeated-at-the-end-of-the-previous-page - but that's asking what it's called, not how to implement. I flagged this as a duplicate by mistake, but can't see how to undo that.

Comment: @e100 Got your flag but unfortunately no way to do that.  Shouldn't be an issue though unless 4 others do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is a perfect opportunity for a scripted solution. The upside of scripting it (vs doing it by hand) is that you could tag the dupes with a label so the process could be updated on reflow. It really shouldn't be that difficult to do in javascript. Check out the [InDesign Scripting forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting) for more complete guidance.

Comment: On the other hand, Scott's right: That's a really terrible idea to revive! We could also bring back obscenely verbose writers who get paid by the en, but why would we?

Comment: or hot type... yeah... that would be great! :)

Comment: @plainclothes, I'm writing the manual for a 1700s-based board game, and all the little details together have helped evoke the period.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project!